# Synology default SSH login directory

Tags: bash, ssh, synology

When I connect to my Synology server via SSH, by default I get into the root directory. I want to change this to my home user folder. I am kind of able to do this via `name@server 'cd /volume1/<user> ; bash'`, but then I get into a different bash interface compared to how I normally 1) log in via `name@server` and 2) then do `cd /volume1/<user>`. I would like to get the result of the latter, but than in the same line of code. What is the best method for doing this?

Comment: Why don't you just change home directory for the user so it would start session with proper folder ? usermod -d /volume1/<user> <user>

Comment: Because by default I still would like to start from the server root directory